# fill in missing values by same values within the group(match known IMEI with missing cellphone model)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a time series/panel data including encrypted IMEI (unique per cellphone but not unique per user) and cellphone brands. Not too many missing values exist in the IMEI but lots of missing values in cellphone brand. Since the unique IMEI corresponds to a unique phone, we can infer the missing brands by IMEI. 
My solution is to construct a IMEI to brand table and `merge(by=IMEI)` with my current data.
I am just curious. Is there any other way to do it? for example, in dplyr or data.table, or just r-base function.My data is large with around 3 million observations.

NOTES: a user could have multiple devices/IMEI; brands are missing some time, either at the starting time, middle or end.

```
# create sample data
user<-rep(letters[1:5],each=6)
time<-rep(1:6,5)
imei<-c(rep(100,6),rep(200,4),NA,201,rep(300,6),rep(400,3),401,404,404,rep(500,5),NA)
brand<-c(rep('Apple',3),NA,NA,'Apple',NA,rep('ZTE',4),NA,NA,NA,NA,rep('Samsung',3),NA,'Huawei',NA,'Nokia','HTC',NA,rep('Moto',6))
dt<-data.frame(time,user,imei,brand)

    #data
  time user imei   brand
1     1    a  100   Apple
2     2    a  100   Apple
3     3    a  100   Apple
4     4    a  100    <NA>
5     5    a  100    <NA>
6     6    a  100   Apple
7     1    b  200    <NA>
8     2    b  200     ZTE
9     3    b  200     ZTE
10    4    b  200     ZTE
11    5    b   NA     ZTE
12    6    b  201    <NA>
13    1    c  300    <NA>
14    2    c  300    <NA>
15    3    c  300    <NA>
16    4    c  300 Samsung
17    5    c  300 Samsung
18    6    c  300 Samsung
19    1    d  400    <NA>
20    2    d  400  Huawei
21    3    d  400    <NA>
22    4    d  401   Nokia
23    5    d  404     HTC
24    6    d  404    <NA>
25    1    e  500    Moto
26    2    e  500    Moto
27    3    e  500    Moto
28    4    e  500    Moto
29    5    e  500    Moto
30    6    e   NA    Moto
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
setkey(dt, imei)
dt[dt, brand := unique(na.omit(brand)), imei]
#     time user imei   brand
#  1:    5    b   NA     ZTE
#  2:    6    e   NA    Moto
#  3:    1    a  100   Apple
#  4:    2    a  100   Apple
#  5:    3    a  100   Apple
#  6:    4    a  100   Apple
#  7:    5    a  100   Apple
#  8:    6    a  100   Apple
#  9:    1    b  200     ZTE
# 10:    2    b  200     ZTE
# 11:    3    b  200     ZTE
# 12:    4    b  200     ZTE
# 13:    6    b  201      NA
# 14:    1    c  300 Samsung
# 15:    2    c  300 Samsung
# 16:    3    c  300 Samsung
# 17:    4    c  300 Samsung
# 18:    5    c  300 Samsung
# 19:    6    c  300 Samsung
# 20:    1    d  400  Huawei
# 21:    2    d  400  Huawei
# 22:    3    d  400  Huawei
# 23:    4    d  401   Nokia
# 24:    5    d  404     HTC
# 25:    6    d  404     HTC
# 26:    1    e  500    Moto
# 27:    2    e  500    Moto
# 28:    3    e  500    Moto
# 29:    4    e  500    Moto
# 30:    5    e  500    Moto
#     time user imei   brand
```

---

Here's a `dplyr` + `zoo::na.locf` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
fillna <- function(x) na.locf(na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
dt <- dt %>% group_by(imei) %>% mutate(brand = fillna(brand))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a classic R way to do it:

```
dt$brand <- levels(dt$brand)[ave(as.numeric(dt$brand), dt$imei, FUN= function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))]
```

ave take a numeric argument and performs FUN on it, by level of the other arguments. It then returns a vector that is the same length as the original data with the same level for every imei.

Because it takes a numeric arguments, you can't just dump the factor into ave and take the longest result. You have to throw in a number. Well, factors map to numbers that correspond to the levels. So, you can find the mean level (after removing missing) and then use that as an index for the original levels.